# Approximate count in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that contains a list of articles. I want to include a line that says how many articles there are in the DB, however I don't want it to show the exact count.

I would like it to round down to the nearest 10, so for example for 105 articles I would like it to say "100+", etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm baffled at all the answers. xP

Comment: They were pretty quick, which I really appreciate. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
floor($num / 10) * 10
```

[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Comment: Going to mark this as the accepted answer. Very simple, and the link to the documentation was appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To do something similar you have to use the logarithm with base = 10 and round it

```
$exp= floor(log($num)/log(10));
$num = pow(10,$exp)."+";
```

This works with 10, 100, 1000 ecc, i think it better do what you asked.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to work for what I need, and I tried it with many different numbers, and it is a bit shorter. I will mark this answer up though as it works as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = 105;
$nearest10 = floor($count / 10) * 10;
```

Comment: Marked this answer up as well. It was the same as an answer already posted, both said "10 mins ago", and I can only pick one accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d0+", $count * 0.1);
```

or

```
echo substr($count, 0, -1), '0+';
```

And the [`round`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/round) function does support it out of the box, too:

```
round($count, -1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

but the plus-sign is missing.

Comment: +1 for the alternative approaches (but don't you need `%u0+` instead?). Also, wouldn't `round($count, -1);` work?

Comment: If you don't want to mess with integer limits: `printf("%.0F0+", $count, floor($count * 0.1));` - `%u` can't handle that much, see http://codepad.org/cQ9Nu619

Comment: Oh! Nevermind, I was confusing `%d` for a float representation.

Comment: @AlixAxel: But the hint on `round` is a good tip. I added it to the answer, thanks to the mode parameter it's actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to use the `COUNT()` Aggregate function of MySQL to fetch the total number of results, or something like that.

Then you will need to use the modulo operator (`%`) with 10 as the base, and then deduct that value from the main result, which will be something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS `total_num_records` FROM `table`";
$resource = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
$totalRecords = $result['total_num_records'];

if ($totalRecords > 0) {
    $remainder = $totalRecords % 10;
    $showHumanFriendlyRecords = ($totalRecords - $remainder);
    $strHumanFriendlyRecords = $showHumanFriendlyRecords . "+";
}
```

Hope it helps.